# Session id keeps changing for every request with https and spring security in IE browser

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internet-explorer, spring-security, jsessionid

I have a spring MVC 4 with spring security application deployed on a websphere 8.5 shared server say server123. I access the application as https app on corporate F5 domain name.

I have this strange issue where session id keeps changing on every servlet request. This causes an infinite redirect loop on IE. However this works on chrome and firefox.

I invoke my application as below where apps/MyApp/ is the context root an MainPage is the controller request mapping url https://example.server.com/apps/MyApp/MainPage .

I have also configured an SSO authentication with UserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter that intercepts the spring redirect auth url /loginSSO. Once the authentication is successful, the forward path /MainPage is lost in IE and redirects to https://example.server.com/apps/MyApp/ and https://example.server.com/apps/MyApp/loginSSO repeatedly.Below is my security config details.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/loginSSO").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginSSO")
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CookieFilter(),
                    ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(new CSRFFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(authFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .requiresChannel()
            .channelProcessors(
                    Arrays.<ChannelProcessor> asList(
                            new InsecureChannelProcessor(),
                            new SecureChannelProcessor()));

    http.portMapper().http(8080).mapsTo(8443).http(80).mapsTo(44)
            .http(9080).mapsTo(9443).http(7777).mapsTo(7443);
}

/**
 * Auth filter.
 * 
 * @return the auth filter
 */
@Bean
public AuthFilter authFilter() {
    AuthFilter authFilter = new AuthFilter();
    try {

        authFilter
                .setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(
                        "/loginSSO"));
        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return authFilter;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");
    return successHandler;
}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

/**
 * Csrf token repository.
 * 
 * @return the csrf token repository
 */
private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

}

Comment: This issue happens only on corporate servers and not on my localhost

Comment: My first guess would be an old IE version + corporate proxy side effects.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This issue was resolved. It happened to be the problem with the application context root configurations in Websphere application.xml file.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. You have to develop more. I am facing to the same issue and you do not give any information about what you have done to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The issue happened on the EAR file context root was not properly mapped on the websphere. So the  jSession cookie context root was not properly set on the browser to maintain the session state. After fixing the context root on server it worked.